# getting the size of an array of promises(protractor)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a list of checkboxes that I want to check if they are checked. I want to loop through the array of objects and check one by one but I cannot get the size of the array. I have tried the following 2 ways but I get different errors.

```
var i, n;
    networkStatusDetail.detailsList.all(by.tagName('div')).then(function(arr){
        console.log(arr.length);
        for(i=0;i<; i++){
            arr.get(i).element(by.model('displayedsites[site.siteid]')).isSelected().then(function(checked){
                expect(checked).toBe(true);
            });
        }
    });
```

With this code above I get an error saying that arr.get() is not a valid function.

The following code does not work because I am unable to get the size of the array. Assigning the size of the array to another variable only works within a promise function, but once the variable is used outside the value is gone.

```
networkStatusDetail.detailsList.all(by.tagName('div')).then(function(size){
        n = size;
        console.log('n = '+n);
    });

    console.log('n outside '+ n);
for(i=0;i<n; i++){
        check.get(i).element(by.model('displayedsites[site.siteid]')).isSelected().then(function(checked){
    expect(checked).toBe(true);
   //   console.log(i);
        });
   }
```

the 2 consoles will print 512 and undefined respectively, showing that the value of n outside of the promise function does not work.

I can only make it work if I manually set the max value of the for loop, but this value can change over time so It's not correct.

If anybody could give me a hand on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know how many checkboxes are there to loop over them -  use [`map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) or [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) instead:

```
element.all(by.model('displayedsites[site.siteid]')).each(function (checkbox) { 
    return checkbox.isSelected().then(function (isSelected) {
        console.log(isSelected);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe for the quick response. Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work with the code above. I got the error Failed: Element is no longer attached to the DOM. Not sure if it has to do with the array having too many elements or just the way it's being done, but it doesn't seem to be looping through the array.

Comment: @polaris interesting, do you see any "is selected" values printed on the console before the error is thrown? Also, on which line in code does it happen? Thanks.

Comment: All of the sudden this seems to be working fine. But to answer your question it said it failed on the line containing return checkbox....
it seems to be something with protractor not being consistent with its error messages. I had similar errors before but it would not fail at the same place.