# Why is protractor finding the incorrect number of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, protractor

I have a page with 5 ng-repeated elements and am trying to verify the correct number are displayed (self.assignmentQuestions represents the server's copy of the array that is supposed to be displayed on the webpage with the ng-repeat):

```
browser.pause()
$$("[ng-repeat='task in newAssignment.questions track by task._id'] > omni-task").then(function(assignmentQuestions) {
  expect(assignmentQuestions.length).toEqual(self.assignmentQuestions.length);
```

While the browser is paused, if I open the console and execute `$("[ng-repeat='task in newAssignment.questions track by task._id'] > omni-task")` jQuery finds 5 elements. When Protractor retrieves the current set of the ElementArrayFinder it is able to find 6 (there should only be 5). Shouldn't protractor be looking up the same CSS as jQuery with the page state being the same and find the same number of elements?

Comment: I don't know, but this sounds related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498021/getting-the-size-of-an-array-of-promisesprotractor. Could also be some sort of quirk in protractor in combination with ng-repeat. Maybe it hides an element as template?

Answer (score 0):

First: in protractor you have the by.repeater selector.
Then you can use count() with returns a promise and then chec the length. This should work:

```
var elements = element.all(by.repeater('task in newAssignment.questions'));
expect(elements.count()).to.become(self.assignmentQuestions.length);
```